# Python3 split() with generator

Tags: python-3.x

In Python3 many methods are returning iterator or generator objects (instead of lists or other heavy objects in python2).

However, I've found that splitting string still returns `list` instead of `generator` or `iteator` :

```
~$ python3
Python 3.2.2
(...)
>>> type('a b c d'.split())
<class 'list'>
```

Is there buildin for splitting string using `generator` or `iterator` ?

(I know we can split it by ourself and write nice generator function. I am curious if there is something in standard library or language to do this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `re.finditer` from the re module => [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.finditer)

In brief:

"""
Returns an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.
"""

I think it will do what you need. For example:

```
import re
text = "This is some nice text"
iter_matches = re.finditer(r'\w+', text)
for match in iter_matches:
    print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Nice you've pointed out from documentation, that it is what I need.

Comment: @JBernardo I've seen this - before commenting check out comments under your post first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex based answer is small but for those who are still new,
and wanted to write one, here is one way to do so:

```
import string

def gsplit(s,sep=string.whitespace):
    word = []

    for c in s:
        if c in sep:
            if word:
                yield "".join(word)
                word = []
        else:
            word.append(c)

    if word:
        yield "".join(word)
       

text = "This is some nice text"

print(type(gsplit(text)))

for i in (gsplit(text)):
    print(i)
```

```
<class 'generator'>
This
is
some
nice
text

[Program finished]
```